# How to mount jar file to tomcat container

Tags: kubernetes

I have a folder in my project, which contains 1 properties file and 1 jar file(db-driver) file.

I need to copy both of these files to /usr/local/tomcat/lib directory on my pod. I am not sure how to achieve this in kubernetes yaml file. Below is my yaml file where I am trying to achieve this using configMap, but pod creation fails with error "configmap references non-existent config key: app.properties"

Target `/usr/local/tomcat/lib` already has other jar files so I am trying to use configMap to not override entire directory and just add 2 files which are specific to my application.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcatdeployment
  labels:
    app:  tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:  tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app:  tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: tomcat
          image: tomcat:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
          - name: appvolume
            mountPath: /usr/local/data
          - name: config
            mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/lib
            subPath: ./configuration
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
      volumes:
        - name: appvolume
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: config-map
            items:
              - key: app.properties
                path: app.properties
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-map
data:
  key:  app.properties
```

Current Directory structure...

```
.
├── configuration
│   ├── app.properties
│   └── mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar
├── deployment.yaml
└── service.yaml
```

Please share your valuable feedback on how to achieve this.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

**kubectl create configmap config-map --from-file=app.properties --from-file=mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar**

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: tomcatdeployment
      labels:
        app:  tomcat
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app:  tomcat
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app:  tomcat
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: tomcat
              image: tomcat:latest
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              volumeMounts:
              - name: config
                mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/lib/conf
              ports:
                - name: http
                  containerPort: 8080
                  protocol: TCP
          volumes:
            - name: config
              configMap:
                name: config-map
```

or

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcatdeployment
  labels:
    app:  tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:  tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app:  tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: tomcat3
          image: tomcat:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
          - name: config
            mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/lib/app.properties
            subPath: app.properties
          - name: config
            mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar
            subPath: mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: config-map
            items:
            - key: app.properties
              path: app.properties 
            - key: mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar
              path: mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar
```

Comment: In config-map first we define data for config-map from where we define volume parts. For your example from where you will be getting this jar file , how it will come in config-map parts ?

Answer (score 0):

it's normal to have this error because in this volume declaration you mentioned that key: app.properties otherwise in the configmap key: app.properties so here the key is key and the value is app.properties so you must in the volume declaration change :

```
volumes:
        - name: appvolume
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: config-map
            items:
              - key: app.properties
                path: app.properties
```

to :

```
   volumes:
            - name: appvolume
            - name: config
              configMap:
                name: config-map
                items:
                  - key: key
                    path: app.properties
```

for more you can refer here : [add-configmap-data-to-a-volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume)

Comment: Thank you @Semah, after this change I am not seeing previous error. But looks like these replaces all content from  /usr/local/tomcat/lib and only keeps app.properties file. I wanted to keep existing files from image as it is and just add this new file to that folder. Am i missing something in my configuration?

Comment: yes ithink this line causes the overwrite subPath: ./configuration you should replace ./configuration with subPath: configuration

Comment: after changing subPath: configuration also it didn't work. I have added my directory structure, so you can see i want to copy all files from configuration folder to /usr/local/tomcat/lib folder in container. Also, there are default tomcat jars which are already present on that location, so it should not delete those. Thank you for all help :)

Comment: when changing  subPath: configuration  what is the result ?

Comment: it removes all files from that directory and adds app.properties file (but with text as app.properties). I have added my project folder structure for reference. So, from root i am executing kubectl create -f deployment.yaml. I am trying to copy both files from configuration to docker path /usr/local/tomcat/lib without over writing any existing files present at that path in docker.

Comment: You should mount path /usr/local/tomcat/lib/configuration and subpath to configuration